# Can I rollback using change_column method in Rails 4 and above?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

Is `change_column` method able to rollback when it is used in migrations in Rails 4 and above?

Here is an example:

```
def change
  change_column etc
end
```

Should I use `up` and `down` methods instead?

Comment: No, you should just use `up` and `down`. Clean and clearer, especially for those who have been with Rails since version 2 and 3.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`change_column` cannot be reverted by default.
Rails cannot know the column definition before the migration, so it cannot roll back to this original definition.

Therefor starting with Rails 4, you can provide Rails with the necessary information.
That's what the [reversible](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/active_record_migrations.html#using-reversible) method is for:

```
def change
  reversible do |dir|
    dir.up do
      change_column :users, :score, :decimal, precision: 6, scale: 2
    end
    dir.down do
      change_column :users, :score, :decimal, precision: 4, scale: 2
    end
  end
end
```

At first glance, this seems more complicated than using `up` and `down`. The advantage is, that you can mix it with reversible migrations.
If i.e. you add a bunch of fields to a table and have to change few fields along, you can use `change_table` and `add_column` together with `reversible` to have a clean and compact migration:

```
def change
  change_table :users do |t|
    t.string :address
    t.date :birthday
    # ...
  end

  reversible do |dir|
    dir.up do
      change_column :users, :score, :decimal, precision: 6, scale: 2
    end
    dir.down do
      change_column :users, :score, :decimal, precision: 4, scale: 2
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do a rollback with change_column and rails say that: This migration uses change_column, which is not automatically reversible.

Comment: Is the answer to original question NO?

Comment: literally the answer to the original question _should I use up an down methods instead?_ is *YES* ... and there are more options.

Answer (score 1):

> It's possible rollback a migration with change_columns in rails 4 or
>   rails 5 with:
>
> `def change end`

Yes, it is possible to rollback a migration with empty (as well as correct non-empty) `change` method.

When you actually have something there, you might not be able to revert a migration with for example, a `remove_column` if you did not specify the type of the column you removed.

Also, if for example you have a `change_column` in `change` method. How should Rails know, which type/name/whatever the column had before the change if not from `down` method? :)

So if you are planning on rolling back and forth, you would want to be as explicit, as possible, so using `up` and `down` is a very good (best, actually) idea.

Comment: I did not express myself well, I've updated the question

Comment: @MatheusSilva, maybe you didn't, but I think i did :) I recommended using up/down + provided an example of why just `change` is not perfect

Comment: Thanks. I seen that the new versions of Rails can revert when the change is remove or rename, but I did not find about  change_column.

Comment: @MatheusSilva older versions could revert remove (which I used in my example), but only if you specify the column type. Try reverting the remove_column without a type specified, from what i remember, you won't be able to do that. Besides, having `up` and `down` is more explicit for people, who sees the migration first time,  so my vote is for using `up`/`down` predominantly

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
change_column_null(table_name, column_name, null, default = nil)
```

To save some code. Activerecord knows how to rollback this one.

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: I just want to apologize for taking so long to update this answer, I originally didn’t understand the question.

When you are writing a migration in Rails you have two approaches you can take you can use `change` or the `up` `down` approach. When you use change it is important to be aware of what your migration is doing, because the `change` construct will attempt to infer what the opposite action would be in the event you have to rollback the migration. Migration methods like `add_column`, `add_index`, `create_table`, etc, have opposite actions rails can infer. A migration like `change_column` however can be literally anything so like Martin said you would need to include the `reversible` block for rails to know what to do when the revert could be ambiguous.

Comment: Not really, if I try do a rollback with change_column rails alerts: This migration uses change_column, which is not automatically reversible.

Comment: Yes it depends on what is being done in the change statement, like adding a column has an reversible action witch rails understands, where as other actions may not.